# Linux command for pseudo terminal

Tags: java, linux, csh, pty

I have a csh script which requires TTY to work properly.
I need to execute this script from a program which does not have TTY (like Java program started from Eclipse).

I tried "script" Linux command and it works in general, but it has a side effect.
This command forks itself with PTY and my csh script runs under child (slave) process.
But when parent (master) process is killed (by Java program), child process remains running and detached to "init" process.

So, is there any way to run csh in pseudo-terminal, so that all processes are killed when killing parent process (which Java program has access to)?

I know that some Java libraries exist for this (pty4j, etc.) but I have no possibilities to use them, so I need a Linux command.

Comment: I think, this referrs to so called IPC. You should try to get familiar with inter process communication. Usually You get child's pid if something forks a child-process. Now perhaps Your, let's say, java application , should first obtain the child's pid after forking and then react to "on close" in order to either kill ( by invoking "kill" ) this process or perhaps send signals to child process, which serves the "quit" or "kill" purpose. The standard command is "kill". As long as You have orphans, they usually always become children of init, therefore You should obtain child's PID s.

Comment: I run the csh script with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"script", "-c", "my_script.csh"});` and use input/output streams to interact. I do not explicitly run the shell. Do you propose to run a parallel shell, go through "ps" output and find all PIDs to be killed? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Ah, I see. You can either share an environment variable, which can get created by "Your" script and filled with the PID of the process, which Your script itself has or even spawns, or You do not execute "script" at all to wrap the execution, just directly use exec l or it's family members. What ever You do, You must get the PID of Your child process, and in this case it seems, as if You want not go for those, which "Script" returns, but for the invoked csh process ( or even those invoked by it ).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: @icbytes Running a process using one of the seven `exec()` functions is not the same as running it through `script(1)`. The question explicitly mentions that the script requires a terminal device to run, so the only reasonable choice is to run it behind a pseudoterminal with `script(1)` or a similar interface.

Comment: Do you have access to the input and output streams of `script(1)`? I.e. can you feed input to the PTY and read the output?

Comment: Yes, I have. Although it gathers all the service symbols like ESC-sequences. My main issue is that process is not completely killed and remains alive (if only csh script does not exit by itself).